# (PHP) Slow response when retrieving data from data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud

So I'm trying to retrieve info from a data extension. I can get the data I need with no problem, but the problem is that there's a pretty significant lag -- sometimes up to three seconds -- and I've traced it to the constructor. The actual retrieval is pretty quick, but the constructor is where the problem falls. Just wanted to see if anybody has experienced this and if you know of a way to speed things up.

I've been using the code example from here...

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_data_from_a_data_extension/

This line is the culprit line:

$client = new ExactTargetSoapClient(EXACT_TARGET_WSDL, array('trace'=>1, 'connection_timeout' => 180));

...and the FuelSDK as documented here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-sdks.meta/mc-sdks/data-extension-row-retrieve.htm

Same issue: slow constructor, fast retrieval. This line takes a long time to execute:

$myclient = new ET_Client();

Any thoughts?? Had some trouble tracing the code using ExactTargetSoapClient, but with ET_Client, I did try to reduce loading times by, for example, instead of having an external config.php file, I put all of the properties directly into the main code to cut down on the time it takes to load a file. But doing that stuff didn't help.